# Prettier errors out when formatting Apex classes

Tags: apex, formatting, prettier

I have prettier and prettier-plugin-apex node modules installed. Formatting LWC and JSON works fine with prettier but get the below error when formatting Apex files. Never had this issue on my old laptop.

Updated the plugins multiple times and has the latest version of npm.

```
["ERROR" - 2:57:47 pm] Error formatting document.
Error: 
    at parseTextWithSpawn (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\src\parser.js:36:11)
    at Object.parse (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier-plugin-apex\src\parser.js:489:21)
    at Object.parse (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier\index.js:13625:19)
    at coreFormat (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier\index.js:14899:14)
    at format (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier\index.js:15131:14)
    at c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier\index.js:57542:12
    at Object.Success [as format] (c:\Users\user12\VSCodeWorkspace\b2c-ordering-dx\EnergyDX\node_modules\prettier\index.js:57562:12)
    at t.default.<anonymous> (c:\Users\user12\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-6.3.2\src\PrettierEditService.ts:492:45)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at s (c:\Users\user12\.vscode\extensions\esbenp.prettier-vscode-6.3.2\dist\extension.js:1:9119)
["INFO" - 2:57:47 pm] Formatting completed in 337.6478ms.
```

Comment: Are you using some of the newer Apex constructs in the code the formatting fails with? Perhaps the Apex plugin is out-of-date? Or was it the case that the plugin used to format the very same code without issue? Have you considered downgrading to the version you used to use?

Comment: I was only thinking to updating everything I have but downgrading to prettier-plugin-apex@1.8.0 did the trick. Thanks @Phil W.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting this so others can find it useful:

If you run into this error, make sure to update your java version to at least 11 as [prettier-plugin-apex version 1.9.0 and above doesn't support for jdk versions below 11](https://github.com/dangmai/prettier-plugin-apex/releases).

[image]

If you don't want to update java version, downgrade prettier-plugin-apex version to 1.8.0 or below(`npm install --save-dev prettier-plugin-apex@1.8.0`).

For more details: https://github.com/dangmai/prettier-plugin-apex/issues/392

Comment: I have already version 11 and still get this error

Comment: @user853710 Maybe vscode is not seeing your Java 11. Check this link : https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/vscode-desktop/java-setup